# Using camel maven plugin with OSGI blueprint

Tags: maven, apache-camel, osgi

I am using camel V2.21.0 and tried to use camel maven plugin. When I run "mvn camel:run" I get the following error:

```
INFO: Copy thread finished.
[ERROR] *************************************
[ERROR] Error occurred while running main from: org.apache.camel.test.blueprint.Main
[ERROR] 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.camel.maven.RunMojo$1.run (RunMojo.java:519)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Gave up waiting for service (objectClass=org.apache.camel.CamelContext)
    at org.apache.camel.test.blueprint.CamelBlueprintHelper.getOsgiService (CamelBlueprintHelper.java:320)
    at org.apache.camel.test.blueprint.CamelBlueprintHelper.getOsgiService (CamelBlueprintHelper.java:281)
    at org.apache.camel.test.blueprint.Main.doStart (Main.java:110)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start (ServiceSupport.java:61)
    at org.apache.camel.main.MainSupport.run (MainSupport.java:170)
    at org.apache.camel.main.MainSupport.run (MainSupport.java:501)
    at org.apache.camel.test.blueprint.Main.main (Main.java:81)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.camel.maven.RunMojo$1.run (RunMojo.java:519)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
[ERROR] *************************************
```

In the POM file I have the camel plugin like:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.21.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <useBlueprint>true</useBlueprint>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: I went through https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-10602 which is a reported issue in V2.18.0, V2.18.1 and V2.19.0